# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement jsonp

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

could you take a look at this json call via jquery ,where am I doing wrong.thank you

html:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btnSubmit"></input>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements1="";
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.pnathan.com/static/elements.json",
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'mycall',
        contentType: "text/plain",
        async: false,
        success: function (data,d) {
            elements1 = data;
            alert(data);
        }
    });

        function mycall(data){
        alert(data);
        }       
    }); 
});
```

here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/erkanayan/U75WG/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You api does not support jsonp.

To support jsonp you server should return response json object wrapped into call to function with name passed as GET parameter.

For example for request `http://www.pnathan.com/static/elements.json?mycall=jQuery1110010831521428190172_1402822462152&_=1402822462153`

It should return something like:

```
jQuery1110010831521428190172_1402822462152({...});
```

Comment: if I change dataType: "jsonp", to json I am getting nothing response

Comment: is there any way to get data ,except of using jsonp ,only using json

Comment: about changing dataType to json - to do this you need to setup proper response to CORS preflight request (more about this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)